# android open the drawerlayout

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
package com.example.androidtestnavigationdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPlanetTitles = new String[5];
        mPlanetTitles[0] = "Roma";
        mPlanetTitles[1] = "Milan";
        mPlanetTitles[2] = "TOTTI";
        mPlanetTitles[3] = "Juve";
        mPlanetTitles[4] = "JJJ";
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // mDrawerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListner());
        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.hello_world,
                R.string.hello_world);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I don't know what should I do in order to open the drawer layout. any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in you Activity:-

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
                MenuItem item) {
            // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
            // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

            /*
             * if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem) item)) { return
             * true; }
             */
            // Handle action buttons
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
        break;

            default:
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
        private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
                ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                if (position == 1) {

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else if (position == 2) {

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
```

For more information [Click Here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)
Here is demo code which helps you...

Comment: I got error on this ` com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem `

Comment: ok then use simple menu.
actually i used action sherlock lib into my project thats why i used to write......

Comment: The code works perfectly, but why is this `DrawerItemClickListener` ? this class is not used that is why eclipse states

Comment: ok,,
DrawerItemClickerListener is used when you want to show/display dialog/popup on the click of list items..